# glReadPixel return fault result

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, glreadpixels

I want to do the 3D-picking on OpenGl by the way of frame pick. On this way I need to use `glReadPixel` to get some information of the pixels on the screen currently, so I test it on  the following way but get the wrong result.
First , I use Callback  `glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback)`and `mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)` to get the current mouse position (screen positon) and the pixel's color(when I change the mouse's position) ,then use `std::cout` to print it .

```
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)   
{
    uint32_t color;
    glm::vec4 c;
    GLfloat stencil;
    glReadPixels(xpos, ypos, 1, 1,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &color);
    c.r = (color & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
    c.g = ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
    c.b = ((color >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
    c.a = ((color >> 24) & 0xFF) / 255.0F;
    std::cout << "color[0]" << c.r<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "color[1]" << c.g << std::endl;
    std::cout << "color[2]" << c.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "color[3]" << c.a << std::endl;
}
```

But the problem is when I render the scene below, and put my mouse on different part of this  scene , the result seems to be wrong. From left-top region to the right-bottom regionm,the RBG should be (1.0,0.0,0.0) , (0.6,0.0,0.4) , (0.4,0.0,0.6) , (0.2,0.0,0.8) , (0.0,0.0,1.0). The pictures are below .

[the return result is (0.4,0.0,0.6) but the right result shoud be (1.0,0.0,0.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdcl2.png)

[the return result is (0.0,0.0,0.1) but the right result shoud be (0.4,0.0,0.6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq7bq.png)

[the return result is (0.8,0.0,0.2) but the right result shoud be (0.4,0.0,0.6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yS2Q.png)

I have try to use the simple examples (draw a triangle) to test the `glReadPixel`, the rusult seems to be right. I do not know why it goes wrong when use my scence. Could anyone give me some  advices ? Or how to do the frame pick picking ? Thank u for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL uses coordinates where the origin (0, 0) is the bottom-left of the window, and +Y is up. You have to convert to OpenGL's coordinate system when reading, since the cursor events use (0, 0) as the top-left of the window, and +Y is down.

```cpp
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    int width, height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
    int ixpos = (int)xpos;
    int iypos = height - 1 - (int)ypos;
    uint32_t color;
    glReadPixels(ixpos, iypos, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &color);
    ...
}
```